# Book about a space war between humans and an invader previously prisoner of a Dyson sphere

Tags: story-identification, books

It had:

- An AI that got its own planet
- An interplanetary train system, with portals on every planet
- An elf-like species that could travel through weird portals called "the paths" or something like it
- no ships, towards the end of the story
- an invader species that has smart immobile units and dumber mobile units
- the artificial intelligence made "restricted intelligence" as a gift to humans
- A nova bomb is made and used towards the end
- People have many implants that make them better at things

Does anyone know the title and author of the book?

Comment: The train bit along with the implants immediately makes me thing of Peter F Hamilton's Commonwealth Saga, but I haven't read most of the series and the plot points aren't ringing any bells.

Comment: (Wow, the new automatic text for dupe closures looks weird and almost confrontational and doesn't really suggest that you're just notifying of a duplicate)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The is *[Pandora's Star](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001NNC0K6)* and *[Judas Unchained](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0345461673)*, the first and second halves of a 2000-page novel by Peter Hamilton set in his Commonwealth saga.  It's a match to your specs in every respect.

Comment: Isn't Pandora's Star the first and Judas Unchained the second?

Comment: @user22484 Yes. You can edit the answer.